# Request method 'POST' not supported - gradle

Tags: java, spring, jsp, gradle

I appreciate that this question has been asked many times on this site, however none of the solutions seem to fit my problem (although please point to one if I am mistaken)

I am trying to submit a form on a .jsp which will then populate a value in a database. My jsp file follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>New Request</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> New Request </h1>
    <form method="POST" action="addRequest**?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}**">
        <p>
        Version: <select name = "versionSelect">
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="A1">Component A::0.0.1</option>
            <option value="A2">Component A::0.0.2</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            Problem: <input type ="text" name="problem">
        </p>
        <p>
            Solution: <input type ="text" name="solution">
        </p>
        <p>
            Request type: 
            <input type ="radio" name="faultType" value="fault" checked> Fault 
            <input type ="radio" name="faultType" value="new"> New Feature
        </p>
        <input type = "submit" value="Create">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="/developer">
        <input type = "submit" value="Go back to home page">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My controller file is below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addRequest", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addRequest(Model model, @RequestParam(value ="version",required=true) String versionSelect,
                                                @RequestParam(value ="problem", required = true) String problem,
                                                @RequestParam(value ="solution", required = true) String solution,
                                                @RequestParam(value ="faultType", required = true) String faultType) {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setVersion(versionSelect);
    request.setProblem(problem);
    request.setSolution(solution);
    request.setFaultType(faultType);

    return new ModelAndView("developer");

    }
```

However, on submitting the form I receive the warning "Request method 'POST' not supported" and the data is not stored. I have looked at the other posts surrounding this and the answers all seem to involve an XML file which I assume means that they are using Spring with Maven. However, I am using Spring with Gradle am struggling to find an appropriate answer.

I have so far added the following line:

```
**?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}**
```

But it didn't fix my problem.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Why the "**" arround the things you added?

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I thought that was part of the HTML, not just for emphasis! You've fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "**" around the code you added:

```
<form method="POST" action="addRequest?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}">
```